# what's the use of EjbContext and how it can be useful in Ejb applications?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

what's the use of EjbContext and how it can be useful in Ejb applications?

In which scenarios we will need to have the EjbContext?
I am creating an application using Ejb. So just want to know if EjbContext can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html) answers this question:

- obtain Caller pricipal, used for security checks
- role checks
- obtain UserTransation for transaction demarcation
- resource lookup
- register timer callbacks